# How to solve a problem of "Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')"

Tags: angular, error-handling, unique-id

How can I solve a problem of *"Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')"*?

I have an Angular project in which I want to have a unique id for every elements, so I use this code:

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbFeu.png)

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqV9o.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way***, *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface.*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71726816/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure idAct is correct? I am not a daily Angular user, but in HTML it’s just id. Try replacing idAct with id.

Also try using the *window.onload* event:

```js
window.onload = (event)=>{
       document.getElementById("uniqueID").innerHTML = id()
}
```

Comment: i did replace it with id but it still shows the same error

Comment: i try it but it didn't work

Comment: @Dorra sorry about the earlier comment, i got confused, you can try window.onload as the p tag may not be loaded into the dom yet when your script is being run. Do this with the id and not idAct